# Why is a circle not a convex set?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Why is a circle not a convex set?

My attempt: I was googling it, but I didn't find the correct answer, as I didn't understand the explanation why a circle is not a convex set as defined here:

[image]

As shown in diagram 1, points A and B and points C and D lie inside the circle, thus I think the circle must be a convex set, as clearly shown in figure 1.

Why isn't the circle a convex set?

Comment: @Arthur, this text seems rather shallow in content (apart from not being worded too well). Doesn't it basically say that the only convex curves are a straight lines?

Comment: "Circle" means just the curve/loop. "Disk" usually means the circular area inside. Your can't connect 2 points on the circle without going through the interior.

Comment: The points inside the circle (e.g. the intersection of the lines AB and CD) do not belong to the circle.

Comment: A set that is not convex is called concave? What?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

They mean just the edge of the circle, without the interior. That is not a convex set.

Answer (score 18):

The confusion arises from the notation.
A circle, in the second part of the sentence, is defined as just the points on the boundary, excluding the interior. From your picture you can see that the line connecting A and B has A and B on the boundary, but the other points in the segment lie in the interior of the circle. Therefore, if we define a circle as the set of points on the boundary, it is not convex.

On the other hand, if a circle is defined as the set of points in the boundary plus those on the interior, it is a convex set.

The sentence in your book is misleading since it did not define what a circle is, and it seems to be using both interchangeably, adding more confusion.

Comment: Did you check out that book to see if it really doesn't define anywhere what a circle is? I mean, usually that definition is in one place, not everywhere where a circle occurs, and it is quite unlikely that this is the very first place where the book mentions a circle. BTW, in mathematics a circle is *always* defined as the line.

Comment: True, but that seems what the OP is confused about

Comment: But I don't think the book is to blame about it.

Comment: I will edit the answer later to reflect that

Comment: If the book were consistent about defining a circle to be the boundary of a disk, it wouldn't say "the interior of a circle is convex" except to mean "the interior of a circle is the empty set, and the empty set is trivially convex". It would say 'the interior of a disk is convex". So I think the book *is* to blame.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I disagree.  A circle has an interior and an exterior (neither of which are part of the circle).  The interior of a circle is a disc, and it is a convex set.

Comment: @MartinBonner The interior of a set $S$ is the union of all open sets contained in $S$, which is empty for the circle. I'm fine with "the region enclosed by the circle" being a disc, but not the interior.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem "Let C be a Jordan curve in the plane R2. Then its complement, R2 \ C, consists of exactly two connected components. One of these components is bounded (the interior) and the other is unbounded (the exterior), and the curve C is the boundary of each component."

Comment: We can play the Wikipedia link game all day. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology). "In mathematics, specifically in topology, the interior of a subset S of points of a topological space X consists of all points of S that do not belong to the boundary of S." This definition applies when you treat the circle as a set, not as a curve, which is pretty clearly what you're doing when you ask "is the circle a convex set?"

Answer (score 6):

A set $A$ is called convex if for each pair $x,y\in A$ holds
$$
(1-t)x+ty\in A\hspace{1cm} \forall t\in[0,1].
$$
If you have a ball like
$$
B_n=\{x\in\mathbb R^n~:~\|x\|\leq 1\}
$$
you can prove that it is convex. But the sphere
$$
S^{n-1}=\{x\in\mathbb R^n~:~\|a\|=1\}
$$
is not convex. Consider some $x\in S^{n-1}$ and you get $-x\in S^{n-1}$ but
$\left(1-\frac12\right)x+\frac12(-x)=0\notin S^{n-1}$.
You might thought about the *disk* $$B_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2~:~x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$$ but the *circle* $$S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2~:~x^2+y^2=1\}$$ is not convex.

Comment: I see. But is there any advantage for excluding the sphere from the set of convex sets?

Comment: We don't "exclude" the sphere to be convex, but it doesn't satisfy the definition to be convex. We can't decide which set is convex and which isn't convex.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is why do we choose a definition that makes the circle unsatisfied with it? Can't we have a better definition that can graph our intuition that the circle is convex?

Comment: Or geometrically, how to see the circle isn't a convex set?

Comment: A definition has to be useful and the definition I gave is in fact very useful for a lot of theorems. You can define a property $A$ such that each convex set and also the circle has the property $A$. But this property is not the same as convexity. Hence if you have the theorem which needs convex sets, in general, you can't use sets with property $A$.You can see geometrically if a set is convex. By definition, a set is convex iff for every two points in the set the line between the two points belongs to the set, which is wrong for the circle.

Answer (score 6):

The circle is given by the black curved line. Note that the white interior is *not* part of the circle.

Now consider the intersection point of the line AB and the line CD. This intersection point clearly lies on the line AB between the points A and B. The points A and B are on the circle, so if the circle were convex, then the intersection point would need to be on the circle as well. But it obviously is not; it in inside the circle. Therefore the circle is not convex.

On the other side, the inside of the circle *is* convex, as if you chose any two points inside the circle, then the full line segment connecting them is also inside the circle.

Answer (score 2):

This is a confusion caused by people using language differently.  When doing mathematics, we must be quite precise in assigning meanings to different terms, which is why we take so much trouble to *define* them.  And the point of a definition is, once we've understood what somebody means by a term, we won't make the mistake of thinking they mean something else!

So here's how we use certain common English words in ordinary ("Euclidean") geometry:

- A **circle** is a closed curve in space, formed by the set of all
  *point*s an equal distance from a fixed point called the **centre** of
  the circle.
- A **disk** (or **disc**) is the set of all points contained *inside* (*)
  a circle, including its centre.

Note that a disk does not *necessarily* include the circle itself!  (When studying *topology* - which is rather like geometry would be if distances weren't fixed or important - we distinguish between a *closed* disk, which includes the **boundary** or outside edge, and an *open* disk, which doesn't.  And we often call a disk a **ball** - think of a squishy rubber ball.)

We also define a **convex set** to be one that includes *every* point that lies on a *line segment* joining any two of its points.  So you can see that the inside (or **interior**) of a disk is a convex set, since even in a squishy rubber ball, any one point that lies between two others of the interior must be in the interior, no matter how much we squish it.  But the outside (or **boundary**) of a disk is not a convex set, since there are points between any two points on the circle that *don't* also lie on the boundary, that is, they lie inside the circle, in the interior of the open disk.  For example, as pointed out in the answer by **celtschk**, the intersection of those two chords AB and CD in your diagram is such an interior point that lies between points of the circle.

(*) Now I haven't defined what I mean by *point*, *inside* or a *line segment*. But in the case of a circle in Euclidean geometry, the ordinary notion of "inside" and "outside" works well enough; a *point* is as small a dot as we can possibly draw in a picture; and a *line segment* is that part of a straight line that connects two points.  More generally, we can't define everything!  Even in mathematics, where we try to be as precise as we can, we sometimes have to say "Enough!" and just accept certain ideas as basic, undefinable notions.  We usually take a geometric point as one of those basic notions.

Answer (score -2):

Because the chord is not placed on the circle.

Comment: @  MIchael Rozenberg   here   it say that every segment joining the  two point on the circle contain point that are not on the circle......im not getting this line  as  from diagram   it is clearly  contain the  point that are on the circle,,,,,,,,,pliz  explain this   what its exactly mean to say ?

Comment: @lomber lego Let $\Phi$ be our circle and $AB$ be a chord. Thus, $\{A,B\}\subset\Phi$. If $\Phi$ is a convex set then for all $C\in AB$, where $AB$ is a segment, we need $C\in\Phi$, which is wrong.

Comment: how is this saying anything different from the text the OP included in her question? If she was confused by that, is this going to clear up the confusion? No, as evidenced by the subsequent comment. I never thought I'd see an answer as lazy and useless as this one get upvotes...

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg still not getting...suppose i take A=(1,1) and B =(-1,-1)  now  using the distance formula i got $ AB^{2} $ = 8,,,now how can i show that C  ∈ AB?

Comment: @lomber lego In your case $C\in AB$ it's equivalent to $C\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t},\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)$, where $t\geq0$. You need $t>0$ only, of course.