# Is the numerical range of Identity operator convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I understand that the numerical range of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is a convex set. However, when I tried with the identity operator, the numerical range is a circle. According to [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516555/why-is-a-circle-not-a-convex-set), the circle is not convex. Hence, I really confuse about that.

What I did is the following.

Suppose that $f = \begin{pmatrix}
f_1\\ 
f_2
\end{pmatrix}$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then $If= \begin{pmatrix}
f_1\\ 
f_2
\end{pmatrix}$. So $\langle If,f\rangle = |f_1|^2 + |f_2|^2 = 1$.

Then the set of $z = \langle If,f\rangle$ is the unit circle. However, the unit circle is not convex.

Could you please show me what my mistake is?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not delete your question after it has been answered.  It is considered very rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric range of $I$ is not the unit circle, it is the singleton $\{1\}$, which is a convex set.

Comment: Relevant: [Numerical range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range)